# Axios response is raw in npm package

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, axios, commonjs

So I have been trying to publish a npm package.
Requisites:-

- CommonJs.
- Axios (I can change this if you have better options)
- typescript

So the server response in json when I wrote the code, but when I publish the code to npm, I'm receiving raw data.

I know sometimes axios response is not valid for JSON.parse to parse. I dont have access to the server. I was expecting response as a json which contains jwt tokens and stuff. I have tried to run the same code from git repo(which I publish but response is raw).

Axios response is

```
data: '\x1F�\b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x03��[��8\x10���~\x1EN\x01\n' +
'�\t\x02�\x12\x14\x12n/�\x02���\b(����\x13�T��<���[�VU��/���ￇgEگ?��lmAx/��\x02\t�]\x10P߮�\x06\x1B\n' +
"HM_\x10���K(�P'Ah��\x00\x00\x12^0��\x15�9h\x04\x07��\x0Ep�\t�I��ju8��ĸ�\x18#sIu@n��|A\x1B\x19#�u\x1D\x06\x10Ĥq���\x1C,P�\x1A�}�i�nk�\r���g�V�_#\x17�LCb��O4��v����À\x1A��\x1FR\x07�\x07\x0F-�\x00
```

Expected response :

```
data:{token:"the_token",refresh_token:"token"}
```

Comment: Can you show your Axios source code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have made changes to the question, let me know how can I solve it.

Comment: It was the axios patch which broke the code. version - 1.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately its still the same or much worse.In the new updated version Axios 1.2.1 i am getting an **AxiosError: unexpected end of file**.
I have a duplicate ticket with
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74700139/npm-axios-1-2-0-library-returning-some-improper-response`.

sample code::
`const { data, status, statusText } = await axios.post(https:auth0.url, body, { headers: { "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" } });`

In version 1.2.0 i was getting **raw data** in version 1.2.1 i am getting **AxiosError: unexpected end of file**. I had to revert it back to older version 1.1.3