# NPM Axios > 1.2.0 Library returning some improper response

Tags: npm, axios

I am using Axios library to retrieve Auth0 access tokens.

```
const { data, status, statusText } = await axios.post( https:auth0.url,
body,
{ headers: { "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" } });
```

`

The issue i have is when i am using Axios 1.1.3 to retrieve access-tokens from Auth0 its giving me a proper response.

But when i update the library to 1.2.0 and higher everything breaks. I am getting a response for the same code as raw data

```
/@����W�{��bhu�E
                :U�ȦG>SQ��6�y:90��w>B���        f�4:cA�P��V/����)��v%�_P�ɳ���ꑄ=lb���-F��zh�^X
��N�ˠ��G�
o����W(�Žx>�͔{�5*�������I������`�
                                ���fA\��x~KS[
j��p�Ӌ<���u�qog�.)0G�FI/��R��OԽ�sm�ԝ{X�vV��s$i���2p`� �h�x_Ц��Z�u�9�X�d���B+P���l �m�h�Y��2���ԙ2
                                                                                                ��Wx0K
�       �Y2IX�d�����P�֎NЂu�qo���f".AJ��+���K枖0�
```

The stranger part is when i try to use the same code to get the result of an open source api.

```
const results = await axios.post("www.7timer.info/bin/api.pl?lon=113.17&lat=23.09&product=astro&output=json",
{ headers: { "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" } });
```

I am getting a correct response.
I believe i am only getting this response when i am receiving a token from Auth0. Atleast in my use case

The error i am receiving when i call Auth0 to get tokens is

```
cause: Error: unexpected end of file
at BrotliDecoder.zlibOnError [as onerror] (node:zlib:189:17) {
errno: -5,
code: 'Z_BUF_ERROR'
}
```

Is anyone else facing the same issue?

Comment: It is fixed in v1.2.1

Comment: Unfortunately in the 1.2.1 i am getting `AxiosError: unexpected end of file.` In the new version no response is given back

Comment: I tested v1.2.1 in local on linux and windows, no problem to install it.
https://github.com/axios/axios/releases

Comment: this is my testing code with [v1.2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74565383/nodejs-axios-response-wrong-encoding/74567820#74567820)

Comment: Strange. I am running node version v16.17.0. Ubuntu as the OS. I am also using the above code which i have posted. I also deleted node_modules and package-lock json file. and installed node_modules from scratch. I am also using the post command.  This is the exact cause of the error `  cause: Error: unexpected end of file
      at BrotliDecoder.zlibOnError [as onerror] (node:zlib:189:17) {
    errno: -5,
    code: 'Z_BUF_ERROR'
  }
}`

Comment: Issue has been fixed. @BenchVue Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[bench-vue](/questions/tagged/bench-vue) Thank you for your sample code. I had to add 'Accept-Encoding' in the request header to receive the tokens. Thank you for your help